# Layouting a dialog for all android versions

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

I have a custom Dialog, which looks different between Api 19 and newer Api's
and I would like to still support Api 19.

I am using the following style :

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

and I build the Dialog as follow:

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogTheme);
```

The Result for API 19 is not correct based on the style:

[image]

in API 20 and newer it looks correct:

[image]

What is wrong or how can I be sure that a style will be correct for all api's ?
Is there something wrong with "Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert" ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` and not `android.app.AlertDialog`. If you use the framework-standard dialog (as opposed to the support library dialog) you'll get the framework-standard appearance.